# Is there any caching for sideloading MS Teams apps

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am working on an MS Teams app and testing it by sideloading it (upload custom app -> upload app package).

I have an OAuth flow that is working, but when I remove the OAuth page domains from validDomain of my app manifest, uninstall, and then re-install app with new app package/manifest, the OAuth flow still works.

Is there some sort of caching for sideloading that is enabling this behavior?

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have removed authentication details such as redirect uri from azure?

Comment: Hi @Prasad-MSFT, yea authentications details such as redirect uri have been removed from azure

Comment: Could you please try clearing cache once and try again?

Comment: Hi @Prasad-MSFT, it worked after I opened and closed MS Teams client!